Is there a new solution to an old problem? Command \includepdf{file.pdf} removes all links specified in file.pdf
I use \includepdf{file.pdf} to include a pdf file that contains links into a tex file. The pdf file produced by this tex file does not contain any links that were present in the original pdf file. Is there a new solution to this old problem?

https://ctan.org/pkg/newpax
